# How to Call Web Service in Web Socket in iOS?

Tags: ios, web, socket.io

currently i am making chat application using Web Socket.
My question is How to Call Web Service in Web Socket ?

Comment: you may check GCDWebServer ...

Comment: https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer         . in this link no mention about web socket

Answer (score 0):

In iOS using swift you can use two [Cocoapods Library](https://cocoapods.org/) which makes your work hassle free and

1) [Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream)
2) [RocketSocket](https://github.com/facebook/SocketRocket)

With reference to Starscream follow are very handy example:

```
import UIKit
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {
    var socket: WebSocket!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080")!)
        request.timeoutInterval = 5
        socket = WebSocket(request: request)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }

    // MARK: Websocket Delegate Methods.

    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
        if let e = error as? WSError {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.message)")
        } else if let e = error {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
             print("websocket disconnected")
        }
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
        print("Received data: \(data.count)")
    }

    // MARK: Write Text Action

    @IBAction func writeText(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        socket.write(string: "hello there!")
    }

    // MARK: Disconnect Action

    @IBAction func disconnect(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if socket.isConnected {
            sender.title = "Connect"
            socket.disconnect()
        } else {
            sender.title = "Disconnect"
            socket.connect()
        }
    }

}
```